# How to send multiple query variables using GraphQL Playground

Tags: json, graphql, graphql-playground

If I have one variable named $external and one named $manifest, which should be JSON, how do I define them *both* as query variables in the GraphQL Playground?

```
{
  "external": "name",
  "manifest": 
    {
    "some": "json",
    }
}
```

This gives me an error: `Expected String but found` }``.

Yes, I am on the query variables tab, something that has caught out many people asking about how to pass a single query variable.

Comment: You can't have that trailing comma in JSON (next to last line)

Comment: Thanks, but it makes no difference. Going to edit that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid trailing commas in JSON (line 5 and originally line 6 as well)

```
{
    "external": "name",
    "manifest": {
        "some": "json"
    }
}
```

is valid JSON

You can test your JSON using [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/)